# Google Ads API: How to Send Batch Requests?

Tags: google-api, google-ads-api, google-api-python-client

I'm using Google Ads API v11 to upload conversions and adjust conversions.
I send hundreds of conversions each day and want to start sending batch requests instead.

I've followed Google's documentation and I upload/ adjust conversions exactly the way they stated.
https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/conversions/upload-clicks
https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/conversions/upload-adjustments

I could not find any good explanation or example on how to send batch requests:
https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/reference/rpc/v11/BatchJobService

Below is my code, an example of how I adjust hundreds of conversions.
An explanation of how to do so with batch requests would be very appreciated.

```py
# Adjust the conversion value of an existing conversion, via Google Ads API
def adjust_offline_conversion(
    client,
    customer_id,
    conversion_action_id,
    gclid,
    conversion_date_time,
    adjustment_date_time,
    restatement_value,
    adjustment_type='RESTATEMENT'):

    # Check that gclid is valid string else exit the function
    if type(gclid) is not str:
        return None
    # Check if datetime or string, if string make as datetime
    if type(conversion_date_time) is str:
        conversion_date_time = datetime.strptime(conversion_date_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    # Add 1 day forward to conversion time to avoid this error (as explained by Google: "The Offline Conversion cannot happen before the ad click. Add 1-2 days to your conversion time in your upload, or check that the time zone is properly set.")
    to_datetime_plus_one = conversion_date_time + timedelta(days=1)
    # If time is bigger than now, set as now (it will be enough to avoid the original google error, but to avoid a new error since google does not support future dates that are bigger than now)
    to_datetime_plus_one = to_datetime_plus_one if to_datetime_plus_one < datetime.utcnow() else datetime.utcnow()
    # We must convert datetime back to string + add time zone suffix (+00:00 or -00:00 this is utc) **in order to work with google ads api**
    adjusted_string_date = to_datetime_plus_one.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') + "+00:00"

    conversion_adjustment_type_enum = client.enums.ConversionAdjustmentTypeEnum
    # Determine the adjustment type.
    conversion_adjustment_type = conversion_adjustment_type_enum[adjustment_type].value

    # Associates conversion adjustments with the existing conversion action.
    # The GCLID should have been uploaded before with a conversion
    conversion_adjustment = client.get_type("ConversionAdjustment")
    conversion_action_service = client.get_service("ConversionActionService")
    conversion_adjustment.conversion_action = (
        conversion_action_service.conversion_action_path(
            customer_id, conversion_action_id
        )
    )
    conversion_adjustment.adjustment_type = conversion_adjustment_type
    conversion_adjustment.adjustment_date_time = adjustment_date_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') + "+00:00"

    # Set the Gclid Date
    conversion_adjustment.gclid_date_time_pair.gclid = gclid
    conversion_adjustment.gclid_date_time_pair.conversion_date_time = adjusted_string_date

    # Sets adjusted value for adjustment type RESTATEMENT.
    if conversion_adjustment_type == conversion_adjustment_type_enum.RESTATEMENT.value:
        conversion_adjustment.restatement_value.adjusted_value = float(restatement_value)

    conversion_adjustment_upload_service = client.get_service("ConversionAdjustmentUploadService")
    request = client.get_type("UploadConversionAdjustmentsRequest")
    request.customer_id = customer_id
    request.conversion_adjustments = [conversion_adjustment]
    request.partial_failure = True
    response = (
        conversion_adjustment_upload_service.upload_conversion_adjustments(
            request=request,
        )
    )
    conversion_adjustment_result = response.results[0]
    print(
        f"Uploaded conversion that occurred at "
        f'"{conversion_adjustment_result.adjustment_date_time}" '
        f"from Gclid "
        f'"{conversion_adjustment_result.gclid_date_time_pair.gclid}"'
        f' to "{conversion_adjustment_result.conversion_action}"'
    )



# Iterate every row (subscriber) and call the "adjust conversion" function for it
df.apply(lambda row: adjust_offline_conversion(client=client
                                                   , customer_id=customer_id
                                                   , conversion_action_id='xxxxxxx'
                                                   , gclid=row['click_id']
                                                   , conversion_date_time=row['subscription_time']
                                                   , adjustment_date_time=datetime.utcnow()
                                                   , restatement_value=row['revenue'])
                                                   , axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve it in the following way:

The conversion upload and adjustment are not supported in the Batch Processing, as they are not listed [here](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/batch-processing/overview).

However, it is possible to upload **multiple** conversions in one request since the [conversions[]](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/reference/rpc/v12/UploadClickConversionsRequest#conversions%5B%5D) field (list) could be populated with several conversions, not only a single conversion as I mistakenly thought.

So if you're uploading conversions/ adjusting conversions you can simply upload them in batch this way:

**Instead of uploading one conversion:**

```
request.conversions = [conversion]
```

**Upload several:**

```
request.conversions = [conversion_1, conversion_2, conversion_3...]
```

**Going the same way for conversions adjustment upload:**

```
request.conversion_adjustments = [conversion_adjustment_1, conversion_adjustment_2, conversion_adjustment_3...]
```

Comment: As you mentioned, you can send a list of ClickConversion objects through and "bulk upload" multiple conversions at a time. I do recommend using the Partial Failure feature to allow successful conversions to upload and not block the ones that fail to upload.